# Menú desplegable no funciona - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Actualmente estoy trabajando un menú horizontal pero cuándo reduzco la ventana para que se convierta en un menú desplegable se forma el ícono pero no me despliega las opciones.

**El código es el siguiente *HTML*:**

```css
.navbar-brand { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn { position: relative; z-index: 2; padding: 4px 20px; margin: 10px auto; transition: transform 0.3s; }

.navbar .navbar-collapse { position: relative; overflow: hidden !important; }
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 22px; }

.navbar .nav-collapse { position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: 0; padding-right: 120px; padding-left: 80px; width: 100%; }
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse { background-color: #f8f8f8; }
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse { background-color: #222; }
.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { border-width: 0; box-shadow: none; }
.nav-collapse>li { float: right; }

.btn.btn-circle { border-radius: 50px; }
.btn.btn-outline { background-color: transparent; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
 background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
 border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
 height: auto !important;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
 transform: translate(0px,-50px);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
 transform: translate(0px,0px);
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; } 

 .navbar .nav-collapse { margin: 7.5px auto; padding: 0; }
 .navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { margin: 0; }
 .nav-collapse>li { float: none; }

 .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
 .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
  transform: translate(-100%,0px);
 }
 .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
 .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
 }

 .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
 .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
  transform: translate(0px,-100%);
 }
 .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
 .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Second navbar for profile settings -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-4">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>-->
    </div>
  
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-4">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Listas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Campañas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Segmentador</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tracking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Herramientas</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href="#">Boletin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>-->
      <li><a href="#">Reporte</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse4">Perfil <i class=""></i> </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse slide-down" role="search" id="nav-collapse4">
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img class="img-circle" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/588909533428322304/Gxuyp46N.jpg" alt="maridlcrmn" width="20" /> Maridlcrmn <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">My profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Favorited</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Tienes que cargar la libreria de jQuery antes que la de Bootstrap

Comment: Listo amigo, publica tu respuesta para calificarte como correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes mal posicionada la libreria jquery, va antes de la libreria js de bootstrap así:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.navbar-brand { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn { position: relative; z-index: 2; padding: 4px 20px; margin: 10px auto; transition: transform 0.3s; }

.navbar .navbar-collapse { position: relative; overflow: hidden !important; }
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 22px; }

.navbar .nav-collapse { position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: 0; padding-right: 120px; padding-left: 80px; width: 100%; }
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse { background-color: #f8f8f8; }
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse { background-color: #222; }
.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { border-width: 0; box-shadow: none; }
.nav-collapse>li { float: right; }

.btn.btn-circle { border-radius: 50px; }
.btn.btn-outline { background-color: transparent; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
height: auto !important;
transition: transform 0.3s;
transform: translate(0px,-50px);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
transform: translate(0px,0px);
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; } 

.navbar .nav-collapse { margin: 7.5px auto; padding: 0; }
.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { margin: 0; }
.nav-collapse>li { float: none; }

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    transform: translate(-100%,0px);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px,-100%);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
}
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    
    <!-- Second navbar for profile settings -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-4">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>-->
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-4">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Listas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campañas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Segmentador</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tracking</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Herramientas</a></li>
   <!--<li><a href="#">Boletin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>-->
   <li><a href="#">Reporte</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse4">Perfil <i class=""></i> </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse slide-down" role="search" id="nav-collapse4">
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img class="img-circle" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/588909533428322304/Gxuyp46N.jpg" alt="maridlcrmn" width="20" /> Maridlcrmn <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">My profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Favorited</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```